# Swift CollectionView Reload Data Problems

Tags: swift

I am using one collectionView and adding multiple data into it. I add numberOfSections to the collectionView with the title "CategoryTitle". I fill these sections with model [section]. I load two strings inside the model variable. So I add data like Model = [[www ..., www ...], [www., Www ..., www]]. But sometimes data is added, sometimes I get an error in numberOfItemsInSection. Sometimes it doesn't load at all. Is it because I used Reload.Data in the wrong place? What is the problem?

[image]

```
           class denemeView: UIViewController {

                var davetiyeKatIsım = [String]()
                var model = [[String]]()
                var davetiyefilee = [String]()
                var davetiyefilee2 = [String]()
               override func viewDidLoad() {
                       super.viewDidLoad()

                davetiyeCEK1()
                    davetiyecek2()
            }

             @objc func davetiyeCEK1(){
            ....

            if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
               for review in baslik {
                if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {   let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
        self.davetiyefilee.append(s)

             }
            self.model.append(self.davetiyefilee)
            self.modelKATE.append(self.davetiyeKatIsım) }

       DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.sonsuzCollec?.reloadData() }  }

               if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                for review in baslik {
                     if let soru_baslik = review["KATEGO.ISIM"] as? String { let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
    self.davetiyeKatIsım.append(s)   }   }

  DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.sonsuzCollec?.reloadData() }
                                                                                                                       }

             @objc func davetiyecek2(){...
               do {
             if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                 for review in baslik {
                   if let soru_baslik = review["KATEGO.ISIM"] as? String {
                    let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
    self.davetiyeKatIsım2.append(s)  } }

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.sonsuzCollec?.reloadData() }
                                                                                                             }
              if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
          for review in baslik {
            if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {
               let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                   self.davetiyefilee2.append(s)   }
    self.model.append(self.davetiyefilee2)
    self.modelKATE.append(self.davetiyeKatIsım2)
    }


      DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.sonsuzCollec?.reloadData() }  }    
    }



    catch let parseError {
                     let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                           print("raw response: \(responseString)")
                                              }
                                          }
                }
                extension denemeView: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
                    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

                     func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
                     if (collectionView == sonsuzCollec) {

                        return kategoriIsımYeni.count

                        }
                }
                  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                      if (collectionView == sonsuzCollec) {
                          let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellSonsuz", for: indexPath) as! sonsuzCell

                        let urlNew = URL(string: model[indexPath.section][indexPath.item])
                        cell.davetiyeFoto.sd_setImage(with: urlNew)

                                            return cell
                               }
                }
```

Comment: Could you indent your code? Select it in XCode, and Cmd+i on it. And re-paste it here. It's harder to read it.

Comment: ı updated code, thanks